# Are most kanji characters morphemes?

Tags: kanji, etymology

I've always assumed that kanji characters are almost always morphemes, but I've hardly seen anyone explicitly state that. I think the idea that kanji usually represent ideas, not pronunciation, played a role in my assumption.

Are most kanji no bigger than, and no smaller than, a single morpheme?

Also, are most words containing multiple kanji characters based on a combination of the meanings of individual characters, like "volcano" being 火山, a combination of the kanji for "fire" and for "mountain"?

Related questions looking for exceptions to "one kanji = one morpheme": [Does Japanese have morphemes that span two kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/does-japanese-have-morphemes-that-span-two-kanji) and [Kanji for native Japanese concepts: Kun'yomi spanning multiple morphemes](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/kanji-for-native-japanese-concepts-kunyomi-spanning-multiple-morphemes)

Comment: Would you consider it still 'one morpheme' if part of the morpheme ends up in an okurigana? (e.g. in 読む the morpheme break is after /m/ and not after /o/)

Comment: "Idea" is not "morpheme", either. Writing, language, and meaning all have different worlds and you may notice it's difficult to find counterparts of something in other worlds.

Comment: 志【こころざし】 is three morphomes: 心【こころ】 +  指【さ】 + し.  承【うけたまわり】 is four morphemes: 受【う】け + 賜【たま】 + わ + り.  Do you mean instead to ask specifically about the *on'yomi*?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes, most of the time each kanji represents a single morpheme. There are exceptions.

Long answer:

The basic principle of kanji *in the original Chinese system* is that 1 character = 1 morpheme.  This plays along well the property of Chinese languages where, in most cases, 1 syllable = 1 morpheme (source: Packard, *The Morphology of Chinese*).  So in the typical Chinese case, 1 character = 1 morpheme = 1 syllable.  There are exceptions even in Chinese (some of them disputed, some undeniable); but that’s the basic principle.  This is accepted by all major linguistic works on writing systems including Rogers, Sproat, DeFrancis etc.; the technical term is **morphography**.

In Japanese, some of the *on'yomi* became two syllables, so the last part of the equation (1 kanji = 1 syllable) breaks even for *on'yomi*.  And then there are *kun'yomi* which are, historically speaking, translations.  Of course *kun'yomi* throw syllabic regularity out of the window (政 = *matsurigoto*). But more than that; since morpheme count doesn’t always translate 1:1, the 1 character = 1 morpheme rule got a lot more exceptions, too:

- In some cases, a Chinese single morpheme, like *léi* "thunder", translates to two or more in Japanese, like *kami-nari* gods-voice = thunder.  As a result, the character for *léi*, 雷, represents two morphemes in *kun-yomi*. Other examples include 唇 *kuchi-biru*, 卵 *tama-go*, 政 *matsuri-goto* above, etc.  This is the morphographical equivalent of the letter 'x' representing two sounds, /ks/, in English.  These exceptional cases aren't morphographical but logographical (they represent whole words).
- In some cases, a polymorphemic Chinese word, like *dà-rén* big-person = "adult", translates to a single Japanese morpheme, like *otona* "adult".  In these cases you need a string of multiple kanji to represent a single morpheme: 大人=*otona*.  This is the morphographic equivalent of a digraph.

  - Note that the original Chinese morpheme breakdown is usually indicative of the meaning (if the compound is transparent, which is normally the case).  This means that, by historical coincidence and *in these cases only*, kanji can be said to be representing meaning, and not morphemes or sounds.  An *otona* is a "big person", in meaning though not in etymology.  Once the practice was established, it was used productively, too; like writing the Portuguese word *tabaco* (tobacco) as 煙草 smoke-herb. These are called "mature *kun* readings" 熟字訓 *jukujikun* in Japanese ("mature" in the sense of "conventional").  They’re a minor part of the system, but they’re part of the system.

Still, the *most common* use of kanji is *on’yomi* (e.g. according to my own corpus research, around 83% of Jōyō readings used in the Japanese wikipedia are *on* and not *kun* or *jukujikun*).  And even for *kun’yomi*, 1:1 morpheme equivalence is the typical case (*ken*→*inu*, *fuu*→*kaze*, etc.) Which means that the *basic principle* of Japanese kanji is still morphography.  It’s just messy morphography.  See Terry Joyce, *The significance of the morphographic principle for the classification of writing systems*, for more discussion.

There’s another sense in which someone may argue that kanji don’t represent morphemes but ideas.  It’s because a single kanji can *potentially* represent different morphemes (typically one *on* and one *kun* reading, but up to 12 alternatives in 生); and these multiple possibilities are normally related by meaning (because the *kun* are conventionalized translations of *on*).  So 犬 can be said to represent the "idea" of dog because both the morphemes *inu* and *ken* (as in *ai-ken*, "beloved dog") can be represented by it, and these two morphemes both mean "dog".

This fact is interesting; it distinguishes Japanese writing from simpler morphography like Chinese, and it has to be acknowledged.  But claiming that it's not morphography is like saying that English letters don’t represent sounds because the letter ‹a› has multiple possible pronunciations.  There’s still a clear underlying principle.  In any specific *use* of 犬, it will represent one morpheme, either *inu* or *ken*, specifically in these sound/meaning pairings (and cause the activation of the specific sound patterns in the reader’s brain, priming them for further use etc.; this has been shown in neurolinguistic research).  What's more, the idea of "dog" as represented by *doggu* or *-ku* (as in 走狗 *sōku* "hunting hound") are not represented by 犬; so even *in potentia*, 犬 doesn’t actually represent the idea of "dog" however it may be expressed, it represents the specific morphemes *inu* and *ken*.

(Compare 犬 to the algarism ‹1›, which represents the mathematical idea of 'oneness' however it's expressed linguistically: ‹1› "one", ‹10› "ten", ‹11› "eleven", ‹100› "hundred", ‹1st› "fir-st", ‹*100 años de soledad*› *"**Cién** años de soledad"*… The mechanics of these two kinds of symbol are similar, but aren’t the same.)

Answer (score -4):

No.
「火山」is one morpheme.

If you believe not, please find an article written by a linguist of Japanese.
I've already introduced a few articles that support my idea.

All Kanji, as far as I know, are one syllable in old Chinese.

Comment: I don't think this fits the standard idea of 'morpheme'.  http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsAMorpheme.htm

Comment: Which part do you think different from the standard idea?

There are some Japanese Morphological Analyzer. And, they work as I explained above.
http://taku910.github.io/mecab/

It is generally translated to 形態素.

Comment: @KeitaODA 形態素解析の「形態素」は言語学の用語を借用してはいますが、工学的に取り扱いやすいよう改変されているので実質的には別物です。「火山」を例にとると、言語学では「火」（火星、火災、放火…）も「山」（山脈、山岳、連山…）も再利用可能な部品なのでそれぞれ単独の形態素です。"symmetry"は"syn-metr-y"くらいに分解されると思います（なお、字の切れ目、音の切れ目で必ず形態素が切れるとも考えません）。

Comment: http://db3.ninjal.ac.jp/SJL/view.php?h_id=0470410600
この大学の教授は、命令も愛国も一つの形態素と考えてますね。すみませんが、最低限、博士号所持者がそのように書いている用例をいただけませんか。火も山も中国語において形態素であることは異論がありませんが、外来語だから切れ目が一致するというならば、ラングドシャとクーデターは、複数の形態素を含むことになりますね。

Comment: 愛国＝愛・国＝love・country (2 words, @1 morpheme each)
愛国 ≠ patriotic = patriot＋ic<- (2 morpheme)
愛国 best translation：patriotic
クーデター (1 morpheme as it is 外来語)
クーデター ≠ coup・d'État (2 words, @1 morpheme each)
例：高さ＝高＋さ (1 word 2 morpheme)

Comment: You should have some references.

Comment: A morpheme is a unit of grammar smaller than the word. It has nothing to do with accent or sounds.　火山 is composed of two separate characters, each of which is a morpheme in itself.

Comment: No. Everyone thinks so but no one can find a single reference.

Comment: By your logic, the word "usability" would be one morpheme, but it is obviously not. If you need references, just check Wikipedia; the reason nobody is giving references is because they don't need to; you're the one with the nonstandard view. Also, snailplane DID give a reference. Also, as mentioned above, because 火 is a morpheme and 山 is a morpheme, it's impossible for 火山 to be a morpheme.

Comment: Chinese characters are morphemes in the Chinese language. They are not in general morphemes in Japanese, although you can argue that they are morphemes specifically in on'yomi vocabulary. Kun'yomi is not strict enough in their mapping to kanji to have kanji considered morphemes there, and they are definitely not morphemes in jukujikun (大和 -> やまと) or single character gairaigo (頁 -> ページ). Following from this, **かざん** (火山) is cognate to Chinese **huǒshān** and is decomposable into two different morphemes, each clearly mapping onto one kanji.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. I never said "a loanword becomes one morpheme", but "a loanword does not necessarily preserve its morphemes." By @Kurausukun's logic, ketchup, Vietnam and Origami are not one morpheme. Could you read this article http://db3.ninjal.ac.jp/SJL/view.php?h_id=0470410600 , which says 愛国 is one morpheme and which is written by a Japanese linguist?

Comment: This article is written by a linguist and professor in a Japanese university. Obviously, this part implicitly assumes that everyone knows 愛国 is a single morpheme.
"""
　二、一個の「自由な形態素」の前またはあと(あるいは前およびあと)に、「付属形式」がついたもの。
　i) 前に「付属形式」がついたもの。
　「小-ねこ」「ご-命令」「うわ-手」……
"""

Comment: This article mentions the definition of morpheme in Leonard Bloomfield's "Language", a good old textbook of linguistics. I guess you know him.
Wikipedia says," A morpheme is the smallest grammatical unit in a language. In other words, it is the smallest meaningful unit of a language." Yes, that gives you a rough idea. But also, you can check this textbook.

Comment: Just because Origami is one morpheme in English doesn't mean it's one morpheme in Japanese. I think you should take a linguistics class.

Comment: Origami is made of two morphemes in Japanese. If you don't understand that part, you cannot follow the logic.

Comment: It is *ridiculously* simple to prove that 火山｛かざん｝ is two morphemes. It is made up of the morphemes 火｛か｝ 'fire' and 山｛ざん｝ 'mountain'. The morpheme 火｛か｝ can also be found in 火事｛かじ｝ 'a fire', and the morpheme   山｛ざん｝ can also be found in 氷山｛ひょうざん｝ 'iceberg'. There's no way you can deny that that's two morphemes, @KeitaODA.